# How to set up OpenCV(which is part of ROS) in Qt creator in Ubuntu12.04

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have **OpenCV2.4.2 installed as part of ROS(Fuerte)** in my computer. I want to use an IDE for my projects, I already have installed Qt creator from Ubuntu Software center.

Is it possible to use ROS opencv in an IDE and work. If yes,can somebody help me with **how to set up/configure Qt creator with the ROS opencv ?**

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60630/how-to-set-up-opencv(which-is-part-of-ros)-in-qt-creator-in-ubuntu12.04/) by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Here is a little trick that I used (if anyone knows a "cleaner" way to do this, please let us know):

1- Create a symbolic link to */opt/ros/fuerte/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc* inside the directory */user/local/lib/pkgconfig*.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
ln -s /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc opencv.pc
```

2- Create the appropriate .pro file for your Qt project

```
TARGET= MyQtProject
TEMPLATE = APP

SOURCES += main.cpp

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

If the file */usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc* already exists you can copy ROS's file with another name, for instance: */usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv_fuerte.pc* and then use *PKGCONFIG += opencv_fuerte*

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2013-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-04-14**:
Thank you for the answer....but when I do cd /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig , I get **bash: cd: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory** .... am I supposed to create a new directory there ??

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2013-04-14**:
Yes, if it does not exist you should create it. Remember to do it as root (sudo)

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-04-15**:
I did exactly as you said... earlier when I tried to run the program it would say **opencv2/opencv.hpp : No such file or directory**... Now it s fine but doesnt display the output image... a terminal opens and stays as such... nothing happens......

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-04-15**:
Do i need to take care of some other settings in Qt creator such as build/Release configuration, etc this is the progam ([http://i.imgur.com/tD8nWzY.png](https://i.imgur.com/tD8nWzY.png)) I tried and .pro file ([http://i.imgur.com/sprITVF.png](https://i.imgur.com/sprITVF.png))

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2013-04-15**:
I tested your code, when I launch it from within Qt environment (using the green "Play" button) a terminal appears and nothing else happens, as you mentioned.But, if I execute the program from a console (find the folder where the project is built and execute ./Hello_World), then it works!

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-04-15**:
Thank u.....yes it works fine if I do as u said.....**Am I supposed to always do this way???** The motive of going for an IDE is quicker access through the GUI...am I right? Any idea where I might hav missed some setting or something ?? did you get any similar problem??

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-04-15**:
Finally I got it working... I changed some settings in Qt creator.... In *Projects tab -> Run settings -> **unselect Run in terminal** option*... Now the code works as I click the green "Play" button !